# DataTables warning: table id on kiwi-tcms v8.4

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Hi I encounter this issue after i deploy it another environment

> DataTables warning: table id=resultsTable - Requested unknown parameter 'plan_id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

but on my local machine it works fine.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60295040/kiwi-tcms-v8-0-database-migration-problem-with-test-runs

Comment: @nanika21 you are not telling us anything useful here. On which page is the error that you see, what are the steps to reproduce, anything else that you have done before that? Does the same error exist on https://public.tenant.kiwitcms.org ?

Comment: Sorry for that, but it is the same exact problem with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60295040/kiwi-tcms-v8-0-database-migration-problem-with-test-runs

what i did was, i upgraded my v5.1 to v8.4 using the upgrade path on the documentation, but on my local it is successfully upgraded and complete the database migration but when i transferred  it on our dev server that error continue to show up on search -> test runs and search -> test plans

Comment: Same thing happened to only one of our users, while others could use the application normally. Re-login to application via Incognito mode resolved the issue.